# Insert or append empty rows to a numpy array

Tags: numpy

There are references to using `np.append` to add to an initially empty array, such as [How to add a new row to an empty numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392497).

Instead, my question is how to allocate extra empty space at the end of an array so that it can later be assigned to.

An example:

```
# Inefficient: The data in new_rows gets copied twice.
array = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)
new_rows = np.square(array)
new = np.concatenate((array, new_rows), axis=0)

# Instead, we would like something like the following:

def append_new_empty_rows(array, num_rows):
  new_rows = np.empty_like(array, shape=(num_rows, array.shape[1]))
  return np.concatenate((array, new_rows), axis=0)

array = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)
new = append_new_empty_rows(array, 2)
np.square(array[:2], out=new[2:])
```

However, the `np.concatenate()` likely still copies the empty data array?
Is there something like an `np.append_empty()`?

Comment: Careful, `np.empty` makes a whole new array.  It's like `np.zeros` except the element values are unpredictable.  You aren't saving any memory or copies by using it.

Comment: That llink has a lot of bad answers.  The only good one(s) stick with list append, and make an array at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that the fastest solution is to create an **empty** larger array and then copy the input array into its initial rows:

```
shape = (1000, 1000)
array = np.ones(shape)
new_shape = (2000, 1000)

def version1():  # Uses np.concatenate().
  new_rows = np.square(array)
  return np.concatenate((array, new_rows), axis=0)

def version2():  # Initializes new array using np.zeros().
  new = np.zeros(new_shape)
  new[:shape[0]] = array
  np.square(array, out=new[shape[0]:])
  return new

def append_new_empty_rows(array, num_rows):
  new = np.empty((array.shape[0] + num_rows, array.shape[1]))
  new[:array.shape[0]] = array
  return new

def version3():  # Initializes new array using np.empty().
  new = append_new_empty_rows(array, num_rows=array.shape[0])
  np.square(array, out=new[array.shape[0]:])
  return new

assert np.all(version1() == version2())
assert np.all(version1() == version3())

%timeit version1()  # 4.34 ms per loop
%timeit version2()  # 3.15 ms per loop
%timeit version3()  # 2.24 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it as follows:

```
array = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)
n_rows = 4
new = np.vstack([array, np.zeros((n_rows, array.shape[1]) )])
```

The `new` array will be this:

```
array([[0., 1., 2.],
   [3., 4., 5.],
   [0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0.]])
```

If what you want is to save some space, then you should consider using the `out` parameter provided by `concatenate`. So it would be like this:

```
array = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)
n_rows = 4
np.concatenate([array, np.zeros((n_rows, array.shape[1]))], out=array)
```

As you can see, the only assignment is `array` and there is not any copy created. It overwrites `array` instead...

Comment: Your last block raises a ValueError.  The `out` isn't big enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you are doing:

Make an array that's big enough for both pieces.  `np.zeros` avoids any illusions that we are saving memory or work.

```
In [15]: arr1 = np.zeros((4,3), int)
In [16]: arr1
Out[16]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Now copy values from the initial (2,3) to part of `arr1`:

```
In [17]: arr1[:2] = arr
In [18]: arr1
Out[18]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

and use the `out` to copy square values to the 2nd part

```
In [19]: np.square(arr[:2], out=arr1[2:])
Out[19]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  4],
       [ 9, 16, 25]])

In [21]: arr1
Out[21]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 0,  1,  4],
       [ 9, 16, 25]])
```

I don't see how that saves any effort or memory compared to:

```
In [22]: np.concatenate((arr, np.square(arr)), axis=0)
Out[22]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 0,  1,  4],
       [ 9, 16, 25]])
```

`concatenate`, under the covers must be making a result array of the right size, and copying the pieces to it.  There's really no getting around that if you want an array that contains both `arr` and `np.square(arr)`.

Comment: I like this direction.  However, wouldn't it be best to allocate `arr1` using `np.empty()`, to save the work of initializing the array, because both parts of the array will be written to exactly once?  Otherwise, the array is first written with zeros, then overwritten again with the final data.  (That's the motivation of `np.empty()`.)

Comment: I've found that the time difference is small enough that its not worth the confusion it a can cause.